# How to correctly send PUT/UPDATE request to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So, I'm currently trying to make change password functionality to my user profile, but I have some issues regarding `PUT`/`UPDATE` request reaching correctly to my **UserController**.

According to Laravel documentation I simply need to add `@csrf` and `@method('PUT')` below the form element, but when make dump request in controller I can see request reaches to the function in my controller but it doesn't take neccesary fields when submitting.

**profile.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('update-password')}}">
    @csrf @method('PUT')

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="old_password" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Current password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="old_password" type="password" class="form-control" required autofocus >

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="new_password" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('New password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" required autofocus >

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password_confirm" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Confirm password') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password_confirm" type="password" class="form-control" required autofocus>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group login-row row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Submit') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updatePassword(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'old_password' => 'required',
        'new_password' => 'required|confirmed',
        'password_confirm' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());

    if (!Hash::check($request->current, $user->password)) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => ['current'=> ['Current password does not match']]], 422);
    }

    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->save();

    return $user;
}
```

Currently when field are submitted it only submits

```
_token: UcJwliogSngHauWCNuDvRtRnZy8NP4lrQeNoZQGG
_method: PUT
```

and just makes redirect (302) back to profile page.

It should submit all the 3 fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send data in your inputs by adding a `name` attribute to them. In order for all of your inputs to work properly you need to add `name` to all of them. An example of it is as such:

```
<input id="old_password" name="old_password" type="password" class="form-control" required autofocus >
```

Note that id is not enough for sending data. For input identification you require `name`.

Comment: Thanks! All fields are now submitted to controller.